# Service principal having role: owner but failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, openshift

I am trying to create some resources using service principal and the SP secret but on creating resource from azure cli it giving error like this
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  "status": "Failed",\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",\r\n    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",\r\n    "details": [\r\n      {\r\n        "code": "InvalidResourceProviderPermissions",\r\n        "message": "The resource provider service principal does not have Network Contributor permission on vnet '/subscriptions/7662b628-/resourceGroups/test-aro/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aro-vnet'."\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"},{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "PrincipalTypeNotSupported",\r\n    "message": "Principals of type Application cannot validly be used in role assignments."\r\n  }\r\n}"},{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "InvalidPrincipalId",\r\n    "message": "A valid principal ID must be provided for role assignment."\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}} any suggestions

On checking the role with Service principal it has "roleDefinitionName": "Owner"

Comment: Even though the Service principal has Owner role it requires Network Contributor permission on vnet to perform the action.

Comment: And could you include the resource you are trying to create?

Comment: any link for this as i need to ask this role from my counter team As they already in deny state if you can share

Comment: i am trying to create azure redhat openshift cluster

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/Azure/ARO-RP/issues/1247#issuecomment-759893095?

Comment: Let me try Rukmini Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the similar error as below:***

[image]

The error "*The resource provider service principal does not have Network Contributor permission on vnet*" usually occurs if the Service Principal doesn't have sufficient permisssions to perform the action.

To resolve the error, assign **`Network Contributor permission`** to the Service Principal like below:

[image]

After assigning the sufficient permissions, I am able to create Azure redhat openshift cluster successfully like below:

```bash
az network vnet create --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP  --name aro-vnet --address-prefixes 10.0.0.0/22

az network vnet subnet create --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --vnet-name aro-vnet --name master-subnet --address-prefixes 10.0.0.0/23

az network vnet subnet create --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --vnet-name aro-vnet --name worker-subnet --address-prefixes 10.0.2.0/23

az aro create --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name $CLUSTER --vnet aro-vnet --master-subnet master-subnet --worker-subnet worker-subnet
```

[image]

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check this [**blog**](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/how-to-deploy-an-azure-red-hat-openshift-cluster-in-the-azure-portal-in-minutes) by Jerome Boutaud which states that Service principal must have contributor role.

**References:**

[The resource provider does not have Network Contributor permission on vnet by Olga Mirensky](https://github.com/Azure/ARO-RP/issues/1247#issuecomment-759893095)

[Create an Azure Red Hat OpenShift 4 cluster - Azure Red Hat OpenShift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/tutorial-create-cluster)

Comment: But from command line i am able to execute these command

Comment: Could you include the snip on what you are trying?

Comment: [az login --service-principal -u axhdddld -p 2A58Q~x --tenant f77d0bdc]

[az deployment group create --name aroDeployment --resource-group test-aro --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters location=eastus --parameters domain=mydomain --parameters clusterName=aro-demo --parameters aadClientId=2608f --parameters aadObjectId=d82ac710-24ffa --parameters aadClientSecret=2A5 ]i am trying with this

Comment: actually on trying from azure cli it taking my id as default so it fail due to lack of access,Tha  i try through cloud bash shell on portal where it give me this error where i login first with service princple

Comment: But today while doing new deployment in similar way for east us error got change The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'      \"message\": \"Resource quota of cores exceeded. Maximum allowed: 21,

Comment: Yeah even I faced the same error, but the cluster was created successfully when checked in the portal. The error occurs when the Resource quota exceeds. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/2b35ozl.png).

Comment: it got creatd but in failed state az aro list-credentials --name aro-cluster --resource-group test-aro
(RequestNotAllowed) Request is not allowed in provisioningState 'Failed'.
Code: RequestNotAllowed
Message: Request is not allowed in provisioningState 'Failed'

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-resource-quota?tabs=azure-cli?

Comment: i was checking the same and this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/602565/aro-creation-fails-with-internal-server-error-and

Comment: Did it work after raising the limits?

Comment: Inform team to do this waiting for their update

Comment: after increasing quota ARO cluster deployed